# iOS - Spotify OAuth redirect hanging at launch screen

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, oauth, libspotify

I am trying to log into Spotify with my Swift app and a new issue came up out of nowhere. After I do the OAuth dance, Safari redirects to my app, then:

- on my iPad mini (9.2.1), hangs forever on launch screen
- on client's iPhone 5S (9.0), crashes on launch screen
- everywhere else (iPhone 5 - 9.1; all simulators - 9.2), launch screen -> app -> ***works correctly***

Deploy target is 8.2

**Background**

There are 7 apps that share a common codebase but branding and some redirect urls and such are different. Only one of them is behaving this way, all the others work as expected.

The most recent changes I made to the app were unrelated to any Spotify stuff. **But we recently switched iTunes Connect accounts from mine to my client's and Spotify accounts from mine to my client's**. This is the closest I've come to debugging it.

One thing that seems strange to me is in the `Info.plist`, the `URL Types => Identifier`. This has also changed and feels like it could be a cause. But in all of the Spotify `ios-sdk` docs, it makes it seem like an arbitrary string.

**Crash is not showing up on client's crash logs.**

Even if you don't have a solution, any debugging advice would be great. I have no clue how to debug something like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Did u try reverting the change and running the build?